# Get price from link

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the price from the following link:

[Price from Link](http://www.reuter.de/duravit-d-code-handwaschbecken-b-36-t-27-cm-weiss-ohne-hahnloch-a644995.php)

I tried the following:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@class='c-price-block__price-price ']/text()")
```

However, I get `#N/A` in the spreadsheet back.

[image]

In Chrome the element gets correctly selected:

[image]

My [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1foUIwoA5WuDgiwYTBAfujHOy8931FNNZwKiHYX1NjvU/edit?usp=sharing).

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IMPORTXML("https://"&A2, "//div[@class='c-price-block__price o-price-text']")
```

[image: 6]

Answer (score 1):

```
=IMPORTXML(A2, "//div[@class='c-price-block__price o-price-text']")
```

[image: 1]